# How to convert http attachment to file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build an AWS lambda function that accepts a file upload and then parses it in memory. The file is an xlsx file, and the content comes in to the lambda function looking like this in the `body` key of the `event`:

Beginning:

```
----------------------------300017151060007960655534
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tag_list"; filename="test-list.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
PK
�y�N docProps/PK
```

And the end of the string looks like this:

```
[Content_Types].xmlPK�;
----------------------------475068475306850797919587--
```

If I do a head/tail of the actual file on my computer, it appears that the file starts at the `PK` and ends at the `xmlPK�;`. I've attempted to slice this section out and create a `BytesIO` object or a `SpooledTemporaryFile`, but none of these options work. They all give me something like invalid seek position, or bad zip file errors.

My goal is to load this xlsx file into memory and then parse it using `openpyxl`.

My current function looks a little something like this currently. I keep trying to format it differently, sometimes I decode it, sometimes not.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_index = event['body'].index('PK')
    file_string = event['body'][file_index:]
    file_end = file_string.index(';')
    file = file_string[:file_end].encode('utf-8')
```

I then try to pass the `file` string into `BytesIO` or a `SpooledTemporaryFile`, but they all give me errors...
Note, I do NOT want to use S3.

Comment: how are you sending the request to the lambda? it looks the body contains a mixture of binary (the xlsx file) and text data (header/footer), is there a way to base64 encode the file before sending it so you can treat the entire body as text?

Comment: @JDD thanks, this is being sent from the browser, so I guess it is possible, but the front end guy says that will be a lot of work. I'll see if we can do it, though

Comment: @JDD thanks again. Encoding the file as a b64 string is super simple for the browser and that's the route we're going now